# Convert to RGBA from "CVPixelBuffer" of ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, swift4.2, cvpixelbuffer

I have a case where I have to convert the ARFrames`(CV420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange)` into CVPixelBuffer of format `CV32BGRA`.

I figured out the format of my ARFrame and found the code in GitHub and stackoverflow to find the function which does conversion and how to proceed with it. But I have been struggling alot to find the end result that will be in the required format.

The calling function in `ViewController`

```
        guard currentBuffer == nil,
            case .normal = frame.camera.trackingState else {
            return
        }

        if let currentFrame = sceneView.session.currentFrame{
            let imageSampler = createImageSampler(from: currentFrame)
        }
    }
    private func createImageSampler(from frame: ARFrame) -> ImageSampler? {
        do {
            return try ImageSampler(frame: frame)
        } catch {
            print("Error: Could not initialize image sampler \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }
```

The main function which converts.

[Code Link](https://github.com/Praveenk8051/Swift/blob/e13fd000da6ba447047bbea3b88806abcee7d85d/ImageSampler.swift#L2)

I'm in the beginner level in swift would love to learn how to do it.